# What is the highest repetition rate achieved for Terawatt and Petawatt-order lasers?

Tags: laser

What is the highest repetition rate achieved for Terawatt and Petawatt-order lasers? respectively.

Source would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick question, you do understand that a terawatt laser might have only a few watts of continuous power, right? Here is 6W laser with 1.5 TW peak power [1.5TW](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-45-12-3313) and a TW class laser with 318 W [TW-class laser](https://www.osapublishing.org/optica/fulltext.cfm?uri=optica-6-11-1423&id=422940). I am not sure but I think that the second is the world record in continuous power for such lasers.

Comment: @JoséAndrade yes, i'm asking for pulsed lasers, that's why I say 'repetion rate'. Anybody?

Comment: I literally gave you 2 links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Petawatt (or Terawatt, because both are just scientific notations of higher orders of 10¹⁵ and 10¹², respectively) lasers are quite available and working around in the labs and facilities. Some of such lasers are striving towards achieving the ability to fire at high repetition rates (of generally one shot per second or more).In view, VEGA-3 is a 30 fs PW laser, firing one shot per second.

Recently, ELI NP achieved the status to host the most powerful laser in the world with a power of 10 PW. In August 2020, the systems had been tested to deliver their nominal power throughout the entire amplifier and the 10 PW compressor in one arm. The missing off-axis parabolas will be delivered in November 2020 (1 PW) and mid 2021 (10 PW).